# Who do I need to do if I want to keep my buffer size low?

Tags: logic-pro, latency

When I set I/O Buffer size to 64 samples (good amount as for me) I start to hear some crackles during the playback. I used this command to disable Apple Internal audio driver (because I use Focusrite Clarett 2pre thunderbolt audio interface)

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

After I disabled I started to hear less crackle but only less – some crackle is still present. So my question is: what do I need to do if I want to get rid of all crackle in project but keeping I/O Buffer Size at 64 samples?

Answer (score 3):

Below is a shot of the latency numbers from Focusrite's page on the Clarett line specifically:

[image]

This chart shows us a few interesting things. First, latency is also a function of sample rate, and more importantly for you, the host software and operating system both affect latency.

So you could try a larger buffer setting with a higher sample rate to see if it give better performance with the same latency, or you could try using software that has lower latency with larger buffer settings (Reaper is very affordable and performs well here).

But most likely what you'll have to do is either upgrade your computer or minimize the amount of work it has to do or both.

Hard drive latency and processing power are the two more likely sources of dropouts and latency issues, but having too little RAM can cause excessive hard drive paging and lead to hard drive problems. Generally you want the most computer you can afford.

But in your particular situation, aside from changing software and increasing the buffer size, you want to reduce the load on your processor and hard drive. It probably goes without saying that you should disable any other background software on the computer. It may also help to disconnect from all networks and disable Bluetooth, etc., essentially go into airplane mode.

After that, there are things you can do within your DAW to free up resources. Plugins are processor intensive, and audio tracks and sample based virtual instruments are disk intensive. The easiest way to free up a lot of computing power is to disable (which is not always the same a mute) as many tracks as you can stand. For any instrument tracks you absolutely need, it usually helps to render them, turn them into audio tracks with all the plugin processing done and rendered, which takes the load off the CPU. Same with audio tracks although you usually get less of a benefit.

As you wrote in a comment, you could bounce the whole thing to two tracks but that's a bit extreme IMHO. Lawrence's suggestion about "freeze" is a good one if your software has it.

Worst case, disable all plugins that are not absolutely necessary. Definitely disable computationally expensive plugins like convolution reverbs and look-ahead peak limiters. Disable anything on the stereo master bus. Disable entire aux return tracks.

Absolute last resort is to double your buffer size and attempt to deal with the latency in your playing. I almost always record audio with low latency monitoring where you don't listen to the track you are recording through the software.

Answer (score -1):

You get a more powerful computer (though that won't necessarily make much difference) or you use software that is coded more efficiently.

Why do you want an ultra-low buffer size?  The usual reason is to minimise latency when playing a virtual instrument from a MIDI controller in realtime.  I find anything under 10ms acceptable, but some people feel lower is required.    You can always reduce the buffer size while tracking and tolerate the odd crackle.  Raise it to a comfortably higher setting when mixing.

Comment: I just want to record the guitar with ultra-low latency. Maybe bounce a project (with backing track) in place and then record? Is it a good idea? Because all of the problems are coming from software instrument tracks.

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Does your DAW program have a 'freeze' function designed for this very purpose?  (Do you really need to disable the internal audio?  Just select the Focusrite in your DAW program.  The onboard system won't jump up and bite you!)